# How to change columns value in reduce function python

Tags: python, pandas

'''

```
dfs = reduce(lambda x,y: pd.merge(x,y, on='just_date', how='outer'), [date_game0, date_game1, date_game2, date_game3,date_game4, date_game5, date_game6, date_game7, date_game8, date_game9, date_game10])
```

'''

I am merging pandas dataframe by using the above code, but the columns names are repeating as shown in picture, how can change the column name for each data frame?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# define a list with column names that you like
cols=['id1','date1','id2','date2', 'diff']   #just an example

# assign list to the df
df.columns=cols
df
```

Comment: Is there any way I can merge the columns and rename them at the same time in reduce function?